# The following system of ODEs can be written in the format dx/dt = Ax where A is a matrix. What is A?

Tags: matlab, matrix, ode

```
The following system of ODEs can be written in the format dx/dt = Ax     where A is a matrix. What is A?

dx1/dt = 4(x2-x1)
dx2/dt = -2*x1 - x2 - 9*x3
dx3/dt = x2 + 5*x3
```

Enter your answer in the following format:
[0 0 0;0 0 0;0 0 0]
(Put no extra spaces)

Comment: This looks like a homework question. Besides, how is this related to MATLAB? This is terrible syntax.

Comment: Did you not learn from your previous questions?  WE AREN'T HERE TO DO YOUR HOMEWORK FOR YOU.

Comment: I don't want the answer, I just want to know how to start the problem. Thank you anyway.

Comment: The last part of your question says `Enter your answer in the following format`.  That to me says ... you want the answer?

Comment: If you need a hint, rearrange each equation so that `x1` comes first, `x2` comes next and `x3` comes last. If any value is missing, replace that with `0` followed by the coefficient... so `f = x1 + x3 --> x1 + 0x2 + x3`.  You'll see that this can roughly be represented as a 3 x 3 matrix.... write it out.

Comment: Thank you !I just came up with the answer and have now posted it.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:[-4,4,0;-2,-1,-9;0,1,5]

because essentially the matrix comes from the original equations:

```
      dx1/dt = 4(x2-x1)

     dx2/dt = -2*x1 - x2 - 9*x3

     dx3/dt = x2 + 5*x3
```

After you simplify the equations, you get

```
 -4x1+4x2+0x3

-2x1-x2-9x3

 0x1+x2+5x3
```

use the first number in front of each x to use it in the matrix.

```
  -4     4     0
  -2    -1    -9
   0     1     5
```

Comment: So you hand solved it. Still not very related to MATLAB

Comment: You are right! It should be [-4,4,0;-2,-1,-9;0,1,5]